# Bootstrap - Responsive search button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Wordpress theme based off Bootstrap 4 (it's a blog themed similarly to our main website).

I'm attempting to add a search field to the category navigation bar. What I'd like is for the search input box and search button to be displayed on devices with a screen width of 783px or greater, and, for the search input box to be hidden (while keeping the search button) on devices with a screen width of 782px or lower. When the user clicks on the search button, the input field will be displayed.

I've managed to style the search field how I'd like it on both viewport sizes, however, I'm unsure of how I can override the search button to display the input box without it submitting a search query. I'd like for the button to still submit a query when users view the site on a device larger than 783px.

**Images**
[image: Screenshot]

My main struggle is working out how to get the search button to submit the form content when the viewport is greater than 783px, and to display the search box when the viewport is less than 782px (using the search button as a toggle to hide/display when there's no text in the search box, and submitting when there is text).

**CSS**

```
.agSearch {
    float: right;
    width: 260px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}

.input-group {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #55595c;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 32px;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn-secondary {
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    border-color: #a6a6a6;
    height: 32px;
}

.btn-secondary.active, .btn-secondary.focus, .btn-secondary:active, .btn-secondary:focus, .btn-secondary:hover, .open>.btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #8d8d8d;
    border-color: #8d8d8d;
}

@media (max-width: 782px) {
.agSearch {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

body > div.category-bar > div > div > form > input[type="text"] {
    display: none;
}

.agSearch {
    width: 32px;
}

.btn-secondary {
        float: right;
}
}
```

**Search Form HTML**

```
<form class="search-form input-group" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search for...', 'bootstrap-four' ); ?>" name="s">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit"><?php _e( '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', 'bootstrap-four' ); ?></button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Is there a simple JQuery implementation I should be using?

Comment: I guess you will have to change the button's onclick based on viewport size in $(window).resize

Comment: Do you know if your page is using the modernizer JS plugin or not? - So I can improve my answer....

Comment: Hi @christoshrousis, the page isn't using the modernizer JS plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to place this within your existing javascript/s, we need to perform the following:

- Test what the current viewport is and if it matches..
- We want to watch when the user clicks the submit button
- Prevent its default behavior so it doesn't submit
- Only submit the form if the text field has content
- Otherwise toggle the visibility state of the text field

I have written out some javascript which says the above, in some simple if statements. Please note when using .matchMedia it must match something that exists in your CSS. I have also given you form an id of "my-form", your text field an id of "my-text-field" and your submit button an id of "my-submit" to make the JS a little more legible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 782px)" );

  if (mq.matches) {
    $('#my-submit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if($('#my-text-field').is(':visible')) {
        if($('#my-text-field').val().length !== 0) {
          $('#my-form').submit();
        } else {
          $('#my-text-field').hide();
        }
      } else {
        $('#my-text-field').show();
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Please note this only works in IE 10 and above...

Comment: Hi @christoshrousis, I've just given your answer a try, but it didn't seem to work. Should I have a class in my CSS called 'matchMedia'?

Comment: My search form looks like this:

`<form id="agSearchForm" class="search-form input-group" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
  <input type="text" id="agSearchTextField" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search for...', 'bootstrap-four' ); ?>" name="s">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="agSearchSubmit" class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit"><?php _e( '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', 'bootstrap-four' ); ?></button>
  </span>
</form>`

I've updated the IDs in the javascript file to match the form.

Comment: You can confirm my logic by removing the media query check because we can assume the text field is only hidden below that width, so try 
`$('#my-submit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if($('#my-text-field').is(':visible')) {
        if($('#my-text-field').val().length !== 0) {
          $('#my-form').submit();
        } else {
          $('#my-text-field').hide();
        }
      } else {
        $('#my-text-field').show();
      }
    });
` and place it outside the mq.matches if statement.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @christoshrousis.

I had to make a slight modification to the Javascript to make it Wordpress-friendly, but it works! Thanks again!

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 782px)" );`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the caveat. I'm glad I pointed you in the right direction, and I'm glad you worked it out on your own. :)